# Why won't this column convert to date format in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, date

Suppose we have the following data frame:

```
date
<character>
Jan-2020
Feb-2020
```

When I try the following code to convert the column from `character` to `date`, I get the error: `character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`.

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
```

Can anyone suggest why?

Comment: Check the as.Date function. You need to specify a format, probably sth. like `format = "%b-%Y`

Comment: Thanks, but `df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%b-%Y")` doesn't work either - any ideas why?

Comment: Hmm, I see. NOt sure why. Let me check.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated

Comment: Ah, because you need a day to create a date variable.

Comment: Is there no way to make it a date variable without? Or some solution that would work?

Comment: @HelpNeeded4 Take a look at the [`anytime`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/anytime/index.html) package.